# Jackson: deserialization of object arrays

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to deserialize a given JSON structure like following into POJOs:

```
[
    {
        "alpha": [
            {
                "serial": 123,
                "date": "24-01-2022",
                "foo": "...",
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "beta": [
            {
                "serial": 456,
                "date": "24-01-2022",
                "bar: "...",
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "gamma": [
            {
                "serial": 789,
                "date": "24-01-2022",
                "foobar": "...""
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key1": "...",
        "key2": "..."
    }
]
```

Alpha, beta, gamma are arrays of different objects that could share a common base type as they have some common properties. However, the last object in the JSON array is different.

The type of the objects in the arrays are determined by the field name (e.g. alpha, betta, gamma). Jackson provides a way to define the type of the object using a "wrapper object" (`@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CUSTOM, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)`), but this assumes the value is an object and not an array.

Currently, I use a list of the following object to deserialize the JSON and interate over it.

```
public class Status {

    @JsonProperty
    List<AlphaStatus> alpha;
    
    @JsonProperty
    List<BettaStatus> betta;
    
    @JsonProperty
    List<GammaStatus> gamma;
    
    @JsonProperty
    String key1;
    
    @JsonProperty
    String key2;
    
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: I assume that there is something on your solution that you don't like. What it is?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Deserialization returns a List<Status> with each Status only containing a single field. It works, but it would prefer it to return a single Status object containing all the properties.